# what is the analog of electronics for quarks or protons?

Tags: electric-circuits, nuclear-physics, quantum-information, quantum-chromodynamics, nuclear-engineering

Is there an equivalent field for quarks or for protons as there is electronics for electrons where you can build engineer and mess around with things? May be even hack ?

Comment: If a hydrogen atom has one proton in its nucleus, ionize it and you have a proton. So "protonics" can occur in chemistry. But quarks are confined in nucleons, it seems to be hard to do anything with them.

Comment: Well, there is [positronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronic_brain)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already do this to some extent when your power supply is an electrolyte-based battery ([a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery), [b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery)) --- there you have motion of both negative and positive ions in the electrolyte.

Electrons are free to move in conductors when the [Fermi](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/fermi.html) [energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level) falls within a band of energy levels rather than in a gap when there are no allowed energies.
However, the band/gap structure of allowed electronic states [is a result of an infinite periodic potential](http://www.mse.ncsu.edu/WideBandgaps/classes/MSE%20704/Handouts/KronigPenney.pdf).  Quarks are bound in nuclei (or even in nucleons), which are finite systems.  In a solid, I suppose that technically both the electrons and the positive ions that make up the lattice are free to move; however the electrons are so much less massive that they always move first.